# Scrape Zillow Lender Profiles

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

i am trying to scrape desired information from zillow lender profiles on this website: https://www.zillow.com/lender-directory/?sort=Relevance&location=Alabama%20Shores%20Muscle%20Shoals%20AL&language=English&page=1

i know how to scrape the info with beautiful soup... im just trying to create a list on clickable links for each profile so i can iterate to each one...scrape desired info(i can do this) and then go back to starting page and go to next profile link... probably a simple solution but ive been trying to get a list of darn clickable links for a couple hours now and i think its time to ask lol

thanks

ive tried a number of different approaches to get the list of clickable links but may have implemented them incorrectly so im open to same suggestions to double check

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time

#Driver to get website...need to get phantomJS going..
driver = webdriver.Chrome(r'C:\Users\mfoytlin\Desktop\chromedriver.exe')
driver.get('https://www.zillow.com/lender-directory/?sort=Relevance&location=Alabama%20Shores%20Muscle%20Shoals%20AL&language=English&page=1')
time.sleep(2)

#Get page HTML data
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
profile_links = []


profile_links = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='zsg-content-item']//a")
for profile in range(len(profile_links)):
    profile_links = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='zsg-content-item']//a")
    profile_links[profile].click()
    time.sleep(2)
    driver.back()
    time.sleep(2)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `find_elements` parameter is wrong here you can try either of followings.

This is the code that works when you use `find_elements`()

```
def find_elements(self, by=By.ID, value=None):
        """
        Find elements given a By strategy and locator. Prefer the find_elements_by_* methods when
        possible.

        :Usage:
            elements = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, 'foo')

        :rtype: list of WebElement
        """
        if self.w3c:
            if by == By.ID:
                by = By.CSS_SELECTOR
                value = '[id="%s"]' % value
            elif by == By.TAG_NAME:
                by = By.CSS_SELECTOR
            elif by == By.CLASS_NAME:
                by = By.CSS_SELECTOR
                value = ".%s" % value
            elif by == By.NAME:
                by = By.CSS_SELECTOR
                value = '[name="%s"]' % value

        # Return empty list if driver returns null
        # See https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/4555
        return self.execute(Command.FIND_ELEMENTS, {
            'using': by,
            'value': value})['value'] or []
```

---

Try any of the following options

```
profile_links = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='zsg-content-item']//a")
```

OR

```
profile_links = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,"//div[@class='zsg-content-item']//a")
```

Here is list when you use above code.

```
['https://www.zillow.comhttps://www.zillow.com/lender-profile/courtneyhall17/', 'https://www.zillow.comhttps://www.zillow.com/lender-profile/SouthPointBank/', 'https://www.zillow.comhttps://www.zillow.com/lender-profile/kmcdaniel77/', 'https://www.zillow.comhttps://www.zillow.com/lender-profile/jdowney75/', 'https://www.zillow.comhttps://www.zillow.com/lender-profile/fredabutler/', 'https://www.zillow.comhttps://www.zillow.com/lender-profile/justindorroh/', 'https://www.zillow.comhttps://www.zillow.com/lender-profile/aball731/', 'https://www.zillow.comhttps://www.zillow.com/lender-profile/1stfedmort/', 'https://www.zillow.comhttps://www.zillow.com/lender-profile/tstutts/', 'https://www.zillow.comhttps://www.zillow.com/lender-profile/sbeckett0/', 'https://www.zillow.comhttps://www.zillow.com/lender-profile/DebiBretherick/', 'https://www.zillow.comhttps://www.zillow.com/lender-profile/cking313/', 'https://www.zillow.comhttps://www.zillow.com/lender-profile/Gregory%20Angus/', 'https://www.zillow.comhttps://www.zillow.com/lender-profile/cbsbankmarketing/', 'https://www.zillow.comhttps://www.zillow.com/lender-profile/ajones392/', 'https://www.zillow.comhttps://www.zillow.com/lender-profile/sschulte6/', 'https://www.zillow.comhttps://www.zillow.com/lender-profile/dreamhomemortgagellc/', 'https://www.zillow.comhttps://www.zillow.com/lender-profile/DarleenBrooksHill/', 'https://www.zillow.comhttps://www.zillow.com/lender-profile/sjones966/', 'https://www.zillow.comhttps://www.zillow.com/lender-profile/BlakeRobbins4/', 'https://www.zillow.comhttps://www.zillow.com/lender-profile/zajones5746/', 'https://www.zillow.comhttps://www.zillow.com/lender-profile/adeline%20perkins/']
```

**Edited**

As I said you need to re-assign element again.

```
    profile_links = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='ld-lender-info-column']//h2//a")
for profile in range(len(profile_links)):
    profile_links = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='ld-lender-info-column']//h2//a")
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", profile_links[profile])
    time.sleep(2)
    driver.back()
    time.sleep(2)
```

Comment: that seems to have worked, now im having troubling iterating to the profile pages, then back out, then to the next profile page...any suggestions? ive been at this for a couple hours now @KunduK

Comment: Well,yes you might getting stale exception error while refresh your page you need to re-assign your variable again while back to main page.

Comment: what do you recommend? @KunduK

Comment: use Beautiful soup  if your page is static not JS render.

Comment: i edited the code above and cant seem to get the stale exception fixed @KunduK

Comment: i get this error now selenium.common.exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted: Element <a href="/lender-profile/courtneyhall17/">...</a> is not clickable at point (60, 545). Other element would receive the click: <a href="/lender-profile/courtneyhall17/" style="position: absolute; width: 100%; height: 100%; top: 0px; left: 0px;"></a>
i used your original code but also got an error so i had to switch len() and range() function in the for loop @KunduK

Comment: sorry my mistake it should be `range(len(profile_links))`

Comment: it still gives that error listed in previous comment @KunduK

Comment: @mcfoyt : check edited option now to get rid of  `ElementClickInterceptedException` use js executor.

Comment: it visits every link now, but literally every single link hahaha anyway to narrow it down to not get duplicates? @KunduK

Comment: This because you have used wrong xpath. try that xpath `//div[@class='ld-lender-info-column']//h2//a`

Answer (score 0):

You can find all the clickable links using this approach. This is written in Java. you can write the equivalent in python.

```
   List<WebElement> Links = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='zsg-content-item']//a"));
    ArrayList<String> capturedLinks = new ArrayList<>();

    for(WebElement link:Links)
    {
        String myLink = "https://www.zillow.com"+ link.getAttribute("href")
        if(!capturedLinks.contains(myLink)) //to avoid duplicates
        {
        capturedLinks.add(myLink);
        }
    }
```

Comment: @mcfoyt Did this approach work for you or not? if not, what is the error you are getting?

Comment: I am getting this error when trying to translate the code you suggested into python---- Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/mfoytlin/Desktop/refinedtest/refined.py", line 13, in <module>
    profile_links = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH("//div[@class='zsg-content-item']//a"))
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable @Sureshmani

Comment: @mcfoyt find_elements will return a collection of webElements. In our case, collection of clickable web elements. This must of stored in a list to iterate it through. please double check the variable type for profile_links

Comment: i made changes above but am still getting the same error, i couldve given the wrong variable type though but im pretty confident i did

Comment: try with single quote on the xpath string - profile_links = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH('//div[@class='zsg-content-item']//a'))

Answer (score 0):

I suppose the following script might do what you wanted to. In short, the script will parse the profile links from it's landing page and then iterate through those links to scrape the name from their target pages.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

url = 'https://www.zillow.com/lender-directory/?sort=Relevance&location=Alabama%20Shores%20Muscle%20Shoals%20AL&language=English&page=1'

with webdriver.Chrome() as driver:
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver,10)
    driver.get(url)
    items = [item.get_attribute("href") for item in wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"h2 > a[href^='/lender-profile/']")))]
    for profilelink in items:
        driver.get(profilelink)
        name = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "h1.lender-name"))).text
        print(name)
```